# Int array can't call out

Tags: java, user-interface

I am confused about my program. How can I get my integer array in my concatenation if I click on some list? Here is the code I'm trying.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.*;

public class JListDemo extends JFrame {
    JList list;
    String[] listColorNames = {"tres", "dos", "piso", "kwatro", "sais"};
    int[] listColorValues = {3, 2, 1, 4, 6};
    Container con;

    public JListDemo() {
        super("List Source Demo");
        con = getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        list = new JList(listColorNames);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        con.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

                con. (listColorValues[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
            }
        }
        );
        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        //setSizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JListDemo test = new JListDemo();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm *really* confused.  What are you trying to do to that `Container`?

Comment: nothing sir i tried if it will work but not . i need to get the price if i select the one of the list sir .

Comment: So how about this:   what is it that you're actually trying to do?  That's where I'm confused.

Comment: im trying to called out my int[] listColorValues when i select one of items in my list sir .

Comment: so if i select tres
it will appear to the bottom the price because it is element[0] the int elem[0] is 3 so the price is 3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you want to do:

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

            JLabel price = new JLabel(listColorValues[list
                    .getSelectedIndex()] + "");

            con.add(price);
            con.revalidate();
        }
    });
```

But, if you want the text to appear below the list then flowLayout is not suitable to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Do not make two different components if they are related instead encapsulated them in a class like this:

```
public class ColorVal {
    private String colorValue;
    private int colorIndex;

public String getColorValue() {
    return colorValue;
}

public void setColorValue(String colorValue) {
    this.colorValue = colorValue;
}

public int getColorIndex() {
    return colorIndex;
}

public void setColorIndex(int colorIndex) {
    this.colorIndex = colorIndex;
}
```

}

And you can do something like this:

```
 public class JavaApplication2 extends JFrame {

JList list;
String[] listColorNames = new String[10];
List<ColorVal> colorValList = new ArrayList<ColorVal>();
ColorVal colorVal = new ColorVal();
Container con;

public JavaApplication2() {
    super("List Source Demo");

    colorVal = new ColorVal();
    colorVal.setColorIndex(2);
    colorVal.setColorValue("dos");
    colorValList.add(colorVal);

    colorVal = new ColorVal();
    colorVal.setColorIndex(1);
    colorVal.setColorValue("piso");
    colorValList.add(colorVal);


    //add your other colors
    con = getContentPane();
    con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    for (int i = 0; i < colorValList.size(); i++) {
        listColorNames[i] = colorValList.get(i).getColorValue();
    }

    list = new JList(listColorNames);

    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    con.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(colorValList.get(list.getSelectedIndex()).getColorIndex()); //do what you want
        }
    });
    setSize(200, 200);
    setVisible(true);
    //setSizable(false);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JavaApplication2 test = new JavaApplication2();
    test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Make use of java objects and classes.